# Правильный вывод изображения в RecyclerView в адаптере

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Реализовал в адаптере вывод картинок из assets в список `RecyclerView`. Элементы списка содержат картинку и два текста. Для картинки использую `RoundedImageView`.

Все работает и выводит, но возникает вопрос, можно ли получше сделать?

```
public class PlantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlantsAdapter.PlantsViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Plant> plantsList;
    private ArrayList<Plant> mFilteredList;
    private ItemSendId itemSendId;

    public class PlantsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public RoundedImageView iconView;
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtFamily;

        public PlantsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            iconView = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconView);
            txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtFamily = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFamily);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (itemSendId != null){
                itemSendId.sendItemId(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }

    }

    public void setItemSendId(ItemSendId itemSendId) {
        this.itemSendId = itemSendId;
    }

    public PlantsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Plant> plantsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.plantsList = plantsList;
        this.mFilteredList = plantsList;
    }

    @Override
    public PlantsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new PlantsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlantsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Plant plant = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(plant.getRusName());
        holder.txtFamily.setText(plant.getClassification());
        System.out.println(plant.getIcon());
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            inputStream = context.getAssets().open("images/icons/" + plant.getIcon() + ".jpg");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            holder.iconView.setBackground(d);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try{
                if(inputStream!=null)
                    inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = plantsList;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<Plant> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Plant plant : plantsList) {

                        if (plant.getRusName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(plant);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Plant>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Интересует собственно этот фрагмент кода, можно ли получше реализовать? Не будет ли приложение падать в каких-то случаях?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlantsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Plant plant = mFilteredList.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(plant.getRusName());
    holder.txtFamily.setText(plant.getClassification());
    System.out.println(plant.getIcon());
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = context.getAssets().open("images/icons/" + plant.getIcon() + ".jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        holder.iconView.setBackground(d);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if(inputStream!=null)
                inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для отображения картинок можете использовать библиотеку [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Она умеет показывать картинки из ассетов. Сократится код и добавится кеширование, что улучшит производительность при прокрутке списка. Не нужно будет каждый раз читать из ассетов.

Пример:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/images/icons/" + plant.getIcon() + ".jpg"))
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Очень удобная библиотека. Буду ею пользоваться)

Comment: Можно ли ее использовать для вывода в Activity одиночной картинки?

Comment: Можно конечно. Точно также.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

В текущей реализации мне не нравится, что Вы каждый раз открываете новый поток – это лишние ресурсы.

Я бы посоветовал не писать своего велосипеда, а воспользоваться каким-либо сторонним средством, которое уже протестировано и оптимизировано, например – [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/images/icons/" + plant.getIcon() + ".jpg").into(iconView);
```

(при использовании `Picasso` получаете возможность кэширования из коробки)

Comment: Какой выбрать Glide или Picasso? Лучше какой?

Comment: @Kolhoznik, Для данной задачи – любой. `Glide` по-функциональнее, но и по-тяжелее.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.. Почитаю про оба и выберу

Comment: @Kolhoznik, Посмотрите [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide).

Comment: @Kolhoznik Glide кроме того производительнее (быстрее) Picasso и использует меньше ресурсов.